# Error in code pertaining to Expected a '>' when hovering over issue

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int height, time, count;
    double CONST g = 9.8, distance;

    cout << "Enter number of seconds the watermelon falls: ";
    cin >> time;
    cout << "Enter height of bridge: ";
    cin >> height;

    while (distance < height && count <= time)
    {
        distance = 0.5 * g * count * count;
        cout << count << distance;
        count++;
        }


}
```

The problem is following the while statement end parentheses after the word "time" when it is hovered over it says "expected a '>'" I am unsure on how to go about fixing this other than using a different loop. Am I missing something oblivious here? Made using Visual Studio Community 2017 IDE C++

Comment: What is `double CONST`? It seems to me that your code is thinking of the template `std::distance`, not the variable you've defined. And I've never seen that particular syntax; do you have a macro defined somewhere called `CONST`?

Comment: `double const g = 9.8; `
 `double distance = 0.0;` is better to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems are all in this line: `double CONST g = 9.8, distance;`

First of all `CONST` is not(!) a reserved `c++` word. 
If you meant for your `g` variable to be constant, you should use `const`:

```
double const g = 9.8, distance;
```

But this line doesn't compile as well, as all of the `const` variables have to be initialized right away. As `distance` mentioned under `double const` type, compiler expects its initialization.

I think, you meant for her to be plain `double` variable:

```
double const g = 9.8;
double distance;
```

Now code compiles without any problems ([proof](https://godbolt.org/z/woVTSN)).